# Loops in Python 3

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, while-loop

How do I get it so that I can make a while loop work with 'or' for example

```
    start = input(("Would you like to start? "))
    while start == "yes" or "YES" or "Yes":
```

Then later on I have the code

```
    start = input(("Would you like to start again? "))
    if start == "no" or "No" or "NO":
       break
```

When I try this code it does not work. It starts the code at the beginning and breaks at the end no matter what I enter. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `or` has higher precedence than `==`,

```
start == "yes" or "YES" or "Yes":
```

will be evaluated as

```
(start == "yes") or ("YES") or ("Yes")
```

You can simply do

```
while start.lower() == "yes":
```

The same way,

```
if start.lower() == "no":
```

Comment: start.lower() in ('y', 'yes')

Answer (score 0):

each statement between the `or` is separated. so you actually check if
`start == "yes"` is `True`
or `"YES"` is `True` etc.
since `"YES"` is not an empty string, it considered as `True` boolean value.

I want to change it to something like:

```
while (start == "yes") or (start == "YES") or (start == "Yes"):
```

or even:

```
while start.lower() == "yes":
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
while start == "yes" or "YES" or "Yes":
```

do this (same with the if one as well):

```
while start == "yes" or start== "YES" or start == "Yes":
```

or, even better, do this:

```
while start.lower() == "yes":
```

You could also do:

```
while start.lower().startswith('y'):
```

so if the user enters anything starting with 'y', it will do whatever is in the while statement.